# Numbers with 1000 digits which are the sum of the 1000th powers of their digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, number-comparison

In the book$^1$ that I am reading,  the author dubs an $n$-digit positive number a *Smallbrain* number if it is equal to the sum of the $n$th powers of its digits, with $371 = 3^3 + 7^3 + 1^3$ given as an example. The question is to prove that there are no Smallbrain numbers with 1000 digits.

The problem is that for $n = 1000$, the sum of the $n$th powers of the digits is at most $1000\cdot9^{1000}$, which is strictly less than the least number with 1000 digits, namely $10^{999}$. I showed this as follows:

$$(*) \iff 9^{1000} < 10^{996}$$

$$\impliedby 9^{1000} < 10^{990}$$

$$\impliedby 9^{10} < \bigg(1+\frac{1}{9}\bigg)^{990}$$

$$\impliedby 9^{10} < 2^{110}$$

using that $\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} \ge 2.$

This question, however, is printed immediately the after a chapter explaining the AM-GM inequality and Cauchy's inequality for $n = 2$. Although I realise that the fact I used can be derived from AM-GM, I doubt that this was expected for the answer. Is there are a more direct way to prove $(*)$ using the two inequalities I mention?

---

1: *A Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics*, Liebeck.

Comment: Well, $1000\ln(9)= 2197.2245<2293.37<996\ln(10)$ is pretty easy, unless there is some reason this needs to be done with pencil and paper.

Comment: @lulu Sure, but my method is already pretty easy and it only used pencil and paper. I'm just wondering if there is a way to do it using AM-GM/Cauchy since those were the topics discussed in the previous chapter for which this question is an exercise. Logarithms have not been mentioned in the book yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weighted AM-GM can solve this pretty easily: $$9^{1000} < 10^{996} \iff 9^{250}<10^{249} \iff 9 <\left(\frac{10}{9}\right)^{249} \iff 9^{\frac{1}{249}} <\frac{10}{9}$$ Note that by AM-GM on $9,1$ with weights $1, 248$ respectively, we get $$9^{\frac{1}{249}}<\frac{9+248}{249}<\frac{10}{9}$$ The last inequality can be easily verified by cross multiplication.